# Scaling a Texture2D without Draw()

Tags: c#, xna, 2d, image-manipulation, scaling

I am trying to scale a `Texture2D` without using the `Draw()` method.  The reason being
I am not going to be drawing the `Texture2D` until I perform further manipulations.  I would be saving the `Texture2D` as a field.

Comment: I'm not sure that you can do this directly to the Texture2D. I'd propose writing a wrapper class that contains the data you will need to draw it how you would like.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what kind of image manipulations you want to perform on your image but I highly recommend not performing scaling before you do those manipulations. If there is any way possible to do so, manipulate your image before you scale it. Xna has already taken care of all the dirty work of scaling for you.

If you want to perform specific pixel operations, `Texture2D.GetData` will work for you but only in small quantities. If you're doing this to hundreds of images, you'll slow down your game drastically. I highly recommend doing some post-processing effects using a customized `Effect`.

Edit: I just thought of a way to do this the way you want to do it. What you can do is draw your scaled texture to a `RenderTarget2D` object and then get the color data from it and manipulate the data however you'd like. An example below:

```
RenderTarget2D renderTarget = new RenderTarget2D(GraphicsDevice, textureWidth, textureHeight, false, GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferFormat, DepthFormat.Depth24);

GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(renderTarget);

spriteBatch.Begin();
//scale and draw your texture here
spriteBatch.End();

GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);
```

This draws the texture to the render target which you can then draw later just like you would any other texture:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(renderTarget, new Rectangle(), Color.White);
```

You can use `renderTarget.GetData` to get color data just like you would with `Texture2D` and manipulate it to your liking.

Comment: Your idea of drawing the texture to a render target was a good idea but am am having problems with the `Color[]` size being incorrect when I am using the `Texture2D.GetData` method and I am not sure how to get the correct size.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I can think is to use `Texture2D.GetData` and store your texture in an array of `Color`, `uint` or whatever, and then perform your scale.
This will require some basic computer graphics knowledge, and I don't think that's the better way to do it.